# PHP reg replace all [hexa] to a font color string?

Tags: php, replace

I have a String, :  `$s="[#efefef]H[#fafafa]I!";`

How I can do a new string for this like:

```
$s2="<font color='#efefef'>H</font><font color='#fafafa'>I</font>!";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<font>` object is obsolete. Use `<span style="color: #efefef;">` instead.

```
preg_replace("/\\[#([0-9a-f]+)\\]([^[]+)/i", "<span style=\"color: #\\1;\">\\2</span>", $s);
```

Comment: i get this: [#efefef]H[#fafafa]I! <span style=""></span><span style=""></span> ....not work

Comment: Try now, sorry, beginner mistake by me :)

Answer (score 1):

For you example data this should work nicely:

```
$s2 = preg_replace('~\[(#[0-9a-f]{6})\]([A-Z])~',
                   "<font color='$1'>$2</font>", $s);
```

You might want to change the `[A-Z]` placeholder for you needs. This only matches one uppercase letter, as in your example.